# Next-auth Receiving 404 after login attempt in Next-auth development env

Tags: next.js, next-auth, github-oauth

Next-auth Receiving 404 after login attempt in Next-auth development env. i have  next-13.4.9 and next-auth-4.22.1, i  tried many ways but didnt helped. not sure whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was placing the file `[...nextauth].ts` into the folder `pages/api/auth`. The folder `pages` should be at same level as the app folder. To make this change effective you should restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom server like `server.js` in your root folder you might  encounter unexpected behaviour since Vercel don't support it right now [Dec 2023].

If this is the case, you could try and deploy it elsewhere, like Netlify.